# Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string

Tags: php

I want to pull 32 values from the database, but not in 32 different transactions. I am getting this warning and I am not grasping what it has a problem with.

```
$team = "SELECT teamname FROM teamnames WHERE";
for ($j = 1; $j <= 32; ++$j) {
    teamid == "$j";
    if ($j != 1) {
        $team .= ",";
    }
    if ($j == 32) {
        $team .= "\")";
    }
}

$teamselect = $db->prepare($team);
$teamselect->execute($team);
for ($y = 1; $y <= 32; ++$y) {    
    $_SESSION["team$y"] = $teamselect->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: `$team` is not a prepared statement.

Comment: You dont need a prepared statement for that select, since you are not using placeholders.

On the other hand you may want to cleanup your code. There is a variable called $teamid that you are not using. And the resulting SQL does not make much sense either (SELECT teamname FROM teamnames WHERE,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,")). Is that your actual code?

Comment: Well, teamid is a column in the database, the values are auto-incremented so I am trying to pull teamname from each teamid in the database.

Answer (score 3):

`PDOStatement::execute` takes an array as its first param where the indexes matches up  to the indexes or keys for the placeholders.

```
$team="SELECT teamname FROM teamnames WHERE teamname.id = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($team);
$stmt->execute(array($yourteamid));
```

Now given your code i would do the following:

```
$ids = range(1,32);

$team = sprintf(
  'SELECT teamnames.teamname FROM teamnames WHERE teamnames.teamid IN (%s)', 
  implode(',', array_fill(1, count($ids), '?'))
);

$teamselect=$db->prepare($team);
$teamselect->execute($ids);

// then do whatever with your results.
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `execute()` command on `PDO`.Then you should be want to use array in `execute()` if you have parameters.Refer following example.

```
$userQuery = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user where id = ?");
$userQuery->execute(array($_SESSION['user']));
$userData = $userQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```